# multiple list protect by rcu

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rcu

Hi,

I am new to rcu locking mechanism in linux kernel.

While trying to understand how rcu works and the provided APIs, I see that rcu_read_lock(), rcu_synchronize() does not take any lock instance. So, lets say I have n independent lists which I want to protect using RCU, are the reads and synchronise() guaranteed to work as they should be?

Pardon me if the question seem too naive

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not relying on a mutex is one of the primary benefits of using RCU (read, copy, update).  Each `rcu_read_lock()` will ensure that the data being read locally isn't modified until its `rcu_read_unlock()` is executed.  The `synchronize_rcu()` will block on all the preceding readers to synchronize the data structure.

Comment: to get more clarity, how does `synchronize_rcu()` wait for specific `rcu_read_unlock()` to be executed before it can unblock and proceed?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with the linux kernel's implementation, but `synchronize_rcu()` only needs to know which `rcu_read_lock()` calls haven't had a matching `rcu_read_unlock()` executed *yet*.  Conceptually, it's an equation for pending ops `rcu_read_lock()` = +1, and `rcu_read_unlock()` = -1.  My guess is that the value is somehow scoped to the executing thread or cpu.